# Javascript function not returning value from inside another function

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone tell me why the `thelocation` is returning as undefined in this example?

```
function codeAddress(business,address,i,locations) {
    var thelocation = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var loc = [business, results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), i];
            return loc;
        } 
    });
    console.log(thelocation);
}
```

Many thanks for the help.

**Edit**

Here's the full context... I have some values coming out of the database as lat & lng but only an address for others.  I have to populate my array to create my map with markers but some of them have to go through the geocoder.  Here's what I have that clearly doesn't work:

```
var locations = [];

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

<?php
    if ( !empty($posts) ) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ( $posts as $mPost ) {

            //If we find a lat/lng override value
            if ( get_field('lat_lng_override', $mPost->ID) ) {
                $latlng = explode(",",get_field('lat_lng_override', $mPost->ID));
                echo "locations[{$i}] = ['". addslashes(str_replace("&","&amp;",$mPost->post_title))."', ".$latlng[0].", ".$latlng[1].", ".$i."];";
            } else {
            //Can't find lat/lng so get it from google
                echo "codeAddress('".addslashes(str_replace("&","&amp;",$mPost->post_title))."','".get_field('business_address', $mPost->ID).", ".get_field('city', $mPost->ID).", ON',".$i.",locations, function(loc){ locations.push(loc); });";
            }

            $i++;
        }
    }
?>

console.log(locations);

function codeAddress(business,address,i,locations, callback) {
    var thelocation = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var loc = [business, results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), i];
        callback(loc);
      } 
    });
}
```

The idea is that my array looks similar to this when I'm done:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Because `geocoder.geocode` doesn't return a value. Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything for the given answers.

Comment: Okay fair enough.  I'm just struggling with my logic and ending up with a full array like the example. Execution is the problem so I'm just looking for ideas, if anyone is inclined to offer them.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.geocode` is an async function, so you need to use a callback!

```
function codeAddress(business,address,i,locations, callback) {
    var thelocation = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var loc = [business, results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), i];
            callback(loc);
        } 
    });
    console.log(thelocation);
}
```

And then to use it:

```
codeAddress(business, address, i, locations, function(location) {
    console.log(location);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoritically speaking you can't catch the location value outside the aync task, cause you just can't say when it will complete..so your gonna have to catch it inside your callback so,

```
function codeAddress(business,address,i,locations) {
var thelocation = geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var loc = [business, results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), i];
        //return location;
 console.log(loc);
 //continue with what you would like to do with the results, something small i assume! :)
    } 
  });

}
```

Comment: "Theoritically speaking" ?

Comment: good answer, not theoretical following on your point of when it will complete you could mention promises but it is outside the scope. Good answer

Comment: @FelixKling i wonder is there a way to catch it on the fly.. Client side of course... Interesting point.. Observables ?

Comment: even still you can only ever catch it inside the callback, no matter how you go about it, if the value ain't there you just ain't gonna see it.. lol

Comment: "on the fly" really makes no sense when applying to async calls - the callback is there because the call is async - you can't do anything with data that hasn't returned yet.